# Eclipse CDT syntax error on __attribute__ keyword

Tags: gcc, indexing, syntax-error, eclipse-cdt

I would like to know if there is a way to get rid of CDT syntax error warnings when using gcc's  "`__attribute__`" keyword.

It goes without saying that I would not like to switch off CDT syntax check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Project->Properties->C/C++ general->Path and Symbols->Symbols

Add-> 
     Name: __attribute__(X)
     Value: (leave blank)
```

Related links: [You can use this technique basically with any offending keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541314/eclipse-cdt-and-unknown-tags)

Comment: This does not work for me.  It produces an error in the build:

`syntax error: unexpected "("`

I assume this is the shell puking on the `(X)` part of the macro.  Is this even supported by GCC?

Answer (score 3):

The "ECLIPSE_THINKS_THIS_IS_SET_BUT_GCC_DOESNT" definition (from **ams**'s answer) really extsts and it called `__CDT_PARSER__`. For example:

```
#ifdef __CDT_PARSER__
#define __FILE__                "<file>"
#define __LINE__                (-1)
#define __DATE__                "<date>"
#define __TIME__                "<time>"
#endif // #ifdef __CDT_PARSER__
```

Hope this will be helpful.

Comment: This is perfect, and I believe the correct answer.  The additional benefit of this approach is that it can be applied to multiple projects without any additional project configuration.

Answer (score 2):

I've not tried it, and I've not used Eclipse for some time, but here's an idea:

In the CDT settings for Eclipse (or maybe just your project) set up a predefined macro (I seem to remember you can tell it what the compiler auto-defines) named `__attribute__` that takes one parameter, and expands to nothing.

Maybe I haven't explained that right. Let me try again with an example. Basically, the aim is to define a macro that works like this:

```
#if ECLIPSE_THINKS_THIS_IS_SET_BUT_GCC_DOESNT
#define __attribute__(X) /* nothing */
#endif
```

but without putting anything actually in your code.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I solved the problem. I'm posting a straight answer and you're getting the bounty.

Answer (score 1):

ziu's answer is also working for XC8 Microchip compilers

```
Name: __interrupt
Value: (leave blank)
```

The function prototype now is clean:

```
void __interrupt ISRs(void);
```

And Eclipse won't complain about it.