# Eclipse CDT syntax error for macro using _Generic keyword

Tags: c, eclipse-cdt

I'm using Oxygen with CDT 9.3.0 built-in.

When I use a macro I defined that uses _Generic, all those macro uses are underlined with "syntax error", but the project compiles fine (which is setup to use my makefiles).

After reading a [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7968217/eclipse-cdt-syntax-error-on-attribute-keyword) so question, and since _Generic begin from C11 possibly not supported by eclipse's code analysis, I tried defining a symbol for my macro definition to empty but it didn't work. (At project settings, C/C++ General->Paths and Symbols->Symbols Tab, GNU C, added symbol CONVERT(...) without a value and added a symbol CONVERT(X), and CONVERT() and CONVERT without a value).

For example my macro is:

```
#define FIRST_(_1, ...) _1
#define FIRST(...) FIRST_(__VA_ARGS__, _1, _2, _3)

#define CONVERT(...)                            \
                _Generic((FIRST(__VA_ARGS__)),  \
                    char*       : toText,   \
                    int         : toInt,    \
                    ) (__VA_ARGS__)
```

and usage point, that gives the syntax error:

```
void* test = CONVERT("testme");
```

Comment: `_Generic` is from the C11 standard. From what I know, Eclipse's "intellisense" does not yet support it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As **@ErikW** pointed out, `_Generic` is a C11 feature that Eclipse CDT's parser does not support yet. [This bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=445297) tracks adding support for it.

<sub>(By the way, [contributions](https://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/contributing) to Eclipse CDT's C11 support are very welcome!)</sub>

---

It is possible to work around this using macros.

The problem with trying to define another version of the `CONVERT(...)` macro in "Paths and Symbols" is that the macros defined there are treated as if you wrote them at the very top of your file. A subsequent redefinition in your actual code overwrites the definition from "Paths and Symbols".

I can think of two approaches to go about this:

---

**Approach 1**

CDT defines a special macro `__CDT_PARSER__` which evaluates to true when it's parsing the code, but false when the code is actually compiled.

You can take advantage of this to define a different version of `CONVERT(...)` for CDT's purposes:

```
#ifdef __CDT_PARSER__
    #define CONVERT(...)
#else
    #define CONVERT(...)                            \
                    _Generic((FIRST(__VA_ARGS__)),  \
                        char*       : toText,   \
                        int         : toInt,    \
                        ) (__VA_ARGS__)
#endif
```

This almost works, but not quite. We still get a syntax error, because this line:

```
void* test = CONVERT("testme", 42);
```

will now expand to:

```
void* test = ;
```

As you can see, we don't actually want an empty expansion for `CONVERT(...)`. We want an expansion that will parse as a variable's initializer. `0` will work:

```
#ifdef __CDT_PARSER__
    #define CONVERT(...) 0
#else
    ...
#endif
```

---

**Approach 2**

Instead of defining a different version of `CONVERT(...)`, we could define `_Generic(...)` itself to be a macro for CDT's purposes.

This time, we can do it in "Paths and Symbols", because there is no redefinition of `_Generic(...)` in the code that would mess it up.

So let's define a symbol in "Paths and Symbols", with `_Generic(...)` as the name and an empty value.

Now, this line:

```
void* test = CONVERT("testme", 42);
```

will expand to:

```
void* test = _Generic((FIRST("testme", 42)),  \
                    char*       : toText,   \
                    int         : toInt,    \
                    ) ("testme", 42)
```

which will in turn expand to:

```
void* test = ("testme", 42);
```

which parses (`("testme", 42)` parses as a parenthesized comma-expression and is thus a valid initializer).

This approach has the advantage that you don't need to modify your actual code, and that it handles all uses of the `_Generic` macro rather than just the one in `CONVERT`.

On the other hand, it's possible that for some other uses of the `_Generic` macro, this particular expansion won't parse. If that's the case, you might be able to come up with a different expansion that will parse for all uses, or else you can go with Approach 1.